# My .net core published executable gives a different directory path than when running the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, console-application, self-contained

I created a dotnet core console that processes txt files. It needs to be located in the same folder as the  txt files in order to work because it runs through all txt files, so defining its current directory is needed. When I run my solution in Visual Studio, it gives the right directory where my app is, but when I publish it as self-contained console and run it from Desktop for example, it gives a wrong directory (C:\users...\cue2n1g0.eiw).
I am using the following line to define the current directory of the console.

```
 string currentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: The exe is really living on the desktop? Not some shortcut to it/the assembly isn't elsewhere?

Comment: Exactly. So when I am configuring the publishing in Visual Studio, I set the Target Location as my Desktop.

Comment: What does `AppContext.BaseDirectory` give you? And how about `Environment.CurrentDirectory`?

Comment: AppContext.BaseDirectory() gives the same thing. Environment.CurrentDirectory brings an error.

Comment: What does "brings an error" mean?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083706/how-to-get-actual-path-to-executable-when-using-netcore-3-0-and-using-the-ppu

Comment: You are a hero. Thanks man. Environment.CurrentDirectory() worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my tests all these worked out the same and returned the true path of the desktop, for my .net 5 console app published there using VS's "publish to folder" option:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
AppContext.BaseDirectory
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: For myself, only Environment.CurrentDirectory is giving the right directory when I publish the console as self-contained.